# JTable 2D array using single array method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to create 2d array of strings with Jtable.
Firstly, i need to create a single array and include my single array to data[][] 
e.g

Based on the given codes on the tutorial ,

```
String data[][]={ {"101","Amit","670000"},    
                      {"102","Jai","780000"},    
                      {"101","Sachin","700000"}};    
String column[]={"ID","NAME","SALARY"};         
JTable jt=new JTable(data,column);
```

i fully understand the tutorial but i have to customised the data[][] to  my needs. Ive tried so many possibilities to break data[][] to a single array but i keep failing. i have a database that will extract all the information.

For an example

```
String[] dataQuery = { callName() , callCost() };
```

Lets say that callname() is calling "john" & "bob" and callCost() is calling "22","44". 
With this data , i am trying to achieve 
{{"john","22"} , {"bob","44"}};

is it even possible to create next value to the next line .

```
String data[][];
for(int i = 0; i <dataQuery.length; i++){
   data = dataQuery[i];
}
```

i know my codes are wrong but im trying my best to illustrate the logic behind it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets say that callname() is calling "john" & "bob" and callCost() is calling "22","44".

First of all that makes no sense. You don't use a database to get an array of all names and then an array of all costs. Each query should return the name/cost as a single row of data. Then you process each row of data.

> I need to create 2d array of strings with Jtable

No you don't. That is only one way to add data to the DefaultTableModel.

So lets start by creating an empty DefaultTableModel:

```
String column[] = {"ID", "NAME", "SALARY"};         
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(column, 0);
```

The above creates a `DefaultTableModel` with no data. Now you can use the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel to add one row of data at a time.

```
String[] dataQuery = { callName() , callCost() };
```

That code doesn't make any sense to me either. If your callName and callCost methods return arrays, then your code should be something like:

```
String[] names = callName();
String[] costs = callCost();
```

Then you can iterate through the arrays and add data to your table model:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    Vector row = new Vector(3);
    row.add( ...); // add the id
    row.add( names[i] );
    row.add( costs[i] );
    model.addRow( row );
}
```

However, even the above solution doesn't really make sense. Typically you don't do multiple queries on the database to get all the "names" and then a second query to get all the "costs". Typically your query is something like:

```
"Select ID, Name, Salary from databaseName"
```

Then you get a `ResultSet` back from the query with each row in the ResultSet containing the 3 pieces of data. Then you simply iterate through the ResultSet one row at a time adding each row of data to the table model.

Search the forum/web. There are plenty of example showing how to use the ResultSet to create a TableModel.

Comment: Thank you , i have missed out that actually we can iterate through a loop using row.add as i was too focused on the 2d array given in the tutorial. However , what is the differences between using "Vector row = new Vector(..)" and just adding the model.addrow(...) . What are the best practices to add the data and why ?

Comment: You can use either an array of objects or a Vector. The dEfaultTableModel will copy the array elements to a vector anyway, so I use the Vector. You do whatever you find easier.